# How can I upgrade a Jenkins build result?

Tags: jenkins

I want to override a failed build indication by setting the build status to "success". Apparently the jenkins-cli will not allow me to do so.

Does anyone know of a way to make it work?

The context is that I have a multiJob project, and some of the sub-builds are non-essential. If I detect a failure of a non-essential build, I do not want the complete build to fail.

Comment: I currently work around the problem by invoking the multiJob Project as a subproject build and set it to ignore any build result, and then use jenkins-cli to set the result after examining the result of the subproject build.

Comment: BTW, I absolutely despise tools that try to enforce some policy on you. I am the Build-Meister, not Jenkins.

Comment: you dont want to have failure scenarios then put all these task as prebuild activities and build you mention exit 1... so always the build will pass.. upgrading the result is not possible

Comment: That's just sad... but my workaround solves my immediate problem, so if you want to make it an answer, saying "You cannot upgrade a build result", preferably with a link someplace explaining why this is implemented that way, you would get you my green checkmark.

Comment: As simple as that,when you do tasks and it fails,build should fail.. but if the tasks are passed even if there is an error you can check and make it fail.Thats the idea behind.. you have jenkins extension point where you can override this using custom build which is trivial and risky